# How to query a range of nodes in xml column SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I've a table which contains 2 columns as following:

[image]

and each XML_DATA column contains following XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="ROWS">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <ROWS>
    <REQUEST_ID>0000017653</REQUEST_ID>
    <FORM_TYPE>POLICYPAGE</FORM_TYPE>
    <POLICY_NUMBER>FCSOTEST13A</POLICY_NUMBER>
    <AGENTNUM>145</AGENTNUM>
    <AGEYRY01>19</AGEYRY01>
    <AGEYRY02>20</AGEYRY02>
    <AGEYRY03>21</AGEYRY03>
    <AGEYRY04>22</AGEYRY04>
    <AGEYRY05>23</AGEYRY05>
    <AGEYRY06>24</AGEYRY06>
    <AGEYRY07>25</AGEYRY07>
    <AGEYRY08>26</AGEYRY08>
    <AGEYRY09>27</AGEYRY09>
    <AGEYRY10>28</AGEYRY10>
    <AGEYRY11>29</AGEYRY11>
    <AGEYRY12>30</AGEYRY12>
    <AGEYRY13>31</AGEYRY13>
    <AGEYRY14>32</AGEYRY14>
    <AGEYRY15>33</AGEYRY15>
    <AGEYRY16>34</AGEYRY16>
    <AGEYRY17>35</AGEYRY17>
    <AGEYRY18>36</AGEYRY18>
    <AGEYRY19>37</AGEYRY19>
    <AGEYRY20>38</AGEYRY20>
</ROWS>
</NewDataSet>
```

Now, I want to filter the xml by POLICY_NUMBER and get all 'AGEYRY' node and their corresponding value in number of rows which will be equal to the number of 'AGEYRY' nodes available in the xml because that is not fixed.
I went through multiple questions posted here but didn't find the answer of my problem.

Comment: That XML isn't complete, so we won't be able to use it (the `ROWS` and `NewDataSet` nodes aren't closed, for example). Valid XML and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: </ROWS>
</NewDataSet> only closing tags were missing.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @x xml = N'<NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="ROWS">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <ROWS>
    <REQUEST_ID>0000017653</REQUEST_ID>
    <FORM_TYPE>POLICYPAGE</FORM_TYPE>
    <POLICY_NUMBER>FCSOTEST13A</POLICY_NUMBER>
    <AGENTNUM>145</AGENTNUM>
    <AGEYRY01>19</AGEYRY01>
    <AGEYRY02>20</AGEYRY02>
    <AGEYRY03>21</AGEYRY03>
    <AGEYRY04>22</AGEYRY04>
    <AGEYRY05>23</AGEYRY05>
    <AGEYRY06>24</AGEYRY06>
    <AGEYRY07>25</AGEYRY07>
    <AGEYRY08>26</AGEYRY08>
    <AGEYRY09>27</AGEYRY09>
    <AGEYRY10>28</AGEYRY10>
    <AGEYRY11>29</AGEYRY11>
    <AGEYRY12>30</AGEYRY12>
    <AGEYRY13>31</AGEYRY13>
    <AGEYRY14>32</AGEYRY14>
    <AGEYRY15>33</AGEYRY15>
    <AGEYRY16>34</AGEYRY16>
    <AGEYRY17>35</AGEYRY17>
    <AGEYRY18>36</AGEYRY18>
    <AGEYRY19>37</AGEYRY19>
    <AGEYRY20>38</AGEYRY20>
</ROWS>
</NewDataSet>';

select 
    t.col.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    replace(t.col.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)'), 'AGEYRY', '') as rownum_from_nodename,
    row_number() over(order by t.col) as rownum_positional,
    t.col.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as nodetext
from @x.nodes('/NewDataSet/ROWS/*[contains(local-name(), "AGEYRY")]') as t(col);
```

Comment: this example is working fine, but I've a table whose XML_DATA column contains this XML. could you please let me know how I can use that table here?

Comment: I modified the query and now it works prefectly:
select 
    t.col.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)'),
    replace(t.col.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)'), 'AGEYRY', '') as rownum_from_nodename,
    row_number() over(order by t.col) as rownum_positional,
    t.col.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as nodetext
from XPRINT_REQUEST 
OUTER APPLY
 XPRINT_REQUEST.XML_DATA.nodes('/NewDataSet/ROWS/*[contains(local-name(), "AGEYRY")]') as t(col)
 
 where POLICY_NUMBER='ABC1234'